# Using `external` selective for TikZ-pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgfplots, overlays, tikz-external

For the following example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,external}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
% following doesn't work
% \tikzset{every baseline/.append code={external/export=false}}
% \tikzstyle{every baseline}+=[external/export=false]
% \tikzstyle{every overlay}+=[external/export=false]

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame Title}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item first item with longer sentences 
      and a \tikz[baseline]{\node[inner xsep=0pt,
      anchor=base, fill=red!60](n1){node};}
  \item second item with pgf plot: \\
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[width=7cm,height=5cm]
        \addplot[color=blue]{sin(deg(x))};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \item third item with \tikz[baseline]{\node[inner xsep=0pt,
      anchor=base, fill=red!60](n2){node};}
  \end{itemize}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,>=latex, shorten >= 3pt, shorten <=3pt]
    \draw[-,red!60,ultra thick](n1.east) -- ($(n1.east) + (.5,0)$)
    |- (n2.east);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% LaTeX-command: "latex -shell-escape"
%%% TeX-PDF-mode: t
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

Exist a smart/lazy way (= some global settings) to not externalize all `overlay` and `baseline` tikz-pictures?

EDIT:
Now using `external/named only=true` and then explicit naming of pgfplots with `\tikzsetnextfilename{filename}`

Comment: While there is no `every baseline` or `every overlay` option, you certainly can append stuff to the `overlay` option by using `\tikzset{overlay/.append code={<stuff here>}}` (see also [\tikzset or \tikzstyle](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372)). Though, it seems, that **a)** the externalization process has to be disabled *before* the environment (in the environment it is to late because when it is read it is already externalized) and **b)** the `external`ization process does not work with `remember picture` at all when I manually disable the externalization for the `overlay`-ed picture.